# Algorithm Analysis - runtime

Tags: analysis, algorithms

Suppose that you have to choose between three algorithms ***A1, A2*** and ***A3*** for a given problem.  The worst-caserunning time for each algorithm is given by:

$W_{1}(n) = 100_{n}$; 
$W_{2}(n) = {2n}log_{10}n$; 
$W_{3}(n) = 0.1n^2$

a)  Order the algorithms from fastest to slowest in the sense of asymptotic worst-case running time.

(b)  Suppose that we run each algorithm on a large problem instance of size ***n***.  Then we feed in an input of size ***$100n$*** and re-run the algorithms on the new input.  What would you expect to happen to the running times, and why?

(c)  Suppose that hardware limitations mean that your algorithm can only accept input of size at most ***$10^6$***. Which algorithm would you prefer, and why?  Answer the same question with ***$10^6$*** replaced by ***$10^3$***.

(d)  For which problem sizes is ***A1*** the best algorithm to use?  Answer the same question for ***A2*** and then for ***A3***.

(e)  Suppose that we have ***$10^9$*** time units available.  What is the maximum input size that can be processed by each of the algorithms in that time?

Can someone please help me with these questions please? I am struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Try looking at the graphs of the functions and try to see which one will eventually win. b) The intended solution is to think about how many times the runtime will increase, i.e. $W_1(100n)/W_1(n)$, etc. c) This question wants you to think about how asymptotic analysis compares with a fixed input size comparison. Just plug in $n = 10^6$ and $n = 10^3$ for the three algorithms and compare. d) Simiarly, observe that if you consider fixed input sizes instead of $n$ tending to infinity, there may be situations where even asymptotically worse algorithms fare better. Find these situations (as in find $n$). e) This is just asking you to solve for $n$ given that $W_i(n) = 10^9$.

Feel free to ask me for clarifications/more hints after you think about these hints!